# Rcpp Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage") "rcpp_hello_world" not available for .Call() for package "mypackage"

Tags: r, rcpp

I've managed to get the `Rcpp.package.skeleton` to INSTALL in Windows by the following commands at the R prompt -

```
Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackage")
system("R CMD build mypackage")
system("R CMD INSTALL mypackage")
library(mypackage)
```

This creates the `mypackage.dll`.  However when I do the following commands -

```
rcpp_hello_world <- function(){ .Call( "rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage")}
rcpp_hello_world()
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in .Call("rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage") : 
"rcpp_hello_world" not available for .Call() for package "mypackage"
```

I run `sessionInfo()` and I get the following:

```
attached base packages:
[1] tools     stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] mypackage_1.0 inline_0.3.13 Rcpp_0.11.1
```

Stating that my new mypackage is there.

Are there any further checks I can do to see what is happening?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you actually install / compile the package?

Comment: Also `system("R CMD INSTALL mypackage")` is wrong. You only do the `build` in the preceding line to create the tarball you should install.  If you insist on doing from R, it should be `system("R CMD INSTALL mypackage_1.0.0.tar.gz")` (or whatever the version number is set to).

Answer (score 38):

FWIW, I just got a similar error while retrofitting an existing R-only package with Rcpp, and the problem was a missing `useDynLib(mypackage)` in `NAMESPACE`.

Comment: Just to add to this, when porting a script between packages with RCPP, one might have used the roxygen tag `@useDynLib myPackage` somewhere and forgot to change it. Another thing to look for are package hooks, like `.onLoad`.

Comment: StackOverflow for the win!  Thank you.

Comment: In my case I already had `#' @useDynLib mypackage`, but what I needed was to add `NULL` the line after.

Answer (score 2):

The package is tested extensively before every release, including on the Windows-using Win-builder.  The regression tests *even include building a package this way* via a call to `package.skeleton()`.

It is also rebuilt by CRAN post-release.  Many people use it.

For all of those people, tests are appropriate and when `long long` cannot be used, it is `#define`-d away.

Now, you insist on building in a non-standard way: no source I know of recommends calling `R CMD INSTALL` via `system()`.  I *suspect* you simply have a `$PATH` mishap and find another wrong `g++` version.

I would suggest to do what the documentation suggests and run

```
  R CMD INSTALL mypackage*tar.gz
```

in a `cmd.exe` prompt.

Answer (score 0):

If the package NAMESPACE file contains the line
`useDynLib(mypackage, .registration = TRUE)`
(perhaps via a roxygen line `#' @useDynLib, .registration = TRUE`), then it is necessary to remove `PACKAGE = "mypackage"` from `.C` / `.Call` function calls:

i.e. 
`.Call( "rcpp_hello_world", PACKAGE = "mypackage")`
becomes `.Call("rccp_hello_world")`.