# Rcpp: C++ functions don't work in R package

Tags: r, rstudio, rcpp, r-package

I have some functions in R and I re-coded them by Rcpp. Each of those functions has a stand-along .cpp file. One function called `add_inflow()`. Previously, I put all cpp functions on my desktop and used `Rcpp::sourceCpp("add_inflow.cpp")`. Then, this c++ function could give me an output value by plugging parameters.

Then I want to embed them into my R package called `stormwindmodel`, by following [Compiled Code, R Packages, Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/src.html#src)

First, I run `devtools::use_rcpp()`, then moved all cpp functions under `src` file. Then, I clicked build&reload button and it was succesfully done. At this point, I found the original R functions were in the Environmental Panel but didn't see my cpp functinos. Then I run `load_all`, and this time cpp functinos showed up. However, when I run `add_inflow_Cpp()` function, Rstudio gave me this output:

```
Error in .Call("stormwindmodel_add_forward_speed_Cpp", PACKAGE = "stormwindmodel",  : 
"stormwindmodel_add_forward_speed_Cpp" not available for .Call() for package "stormwindmodel"
```

Did I miss any steps? Any suggestion to me?

If the question was not of good enough quality then please give me feedback, I will edit it as soon as possible.

Comment: did you remember `useDynLib` in your NAMESPACE file?

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think I did that. Actually I don't know how to do that. The guide book by Hadley said `devtools::use_rcpp()` it did `useDynLib` for me. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @BenBolker How to check if I did that?

Comment: look in your NAMESPACE file and see if there's a useDynLib line in there?

Comment: So you tried Hadley's guide and it didn't work. May I consider to use what _package authors suggest_ and try `Rcpp.package.skeleton()` (and preferably with package pkgKitten installed)?  I just used that this morning and it worked as expected...

Comment: BTW googling the error message finds http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594238/rcpp-rcpp-package-skeletonmypackage-rcpp-hello-world-not-available-for-ca (which mentions `useDynLib` in one of the answers); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37336916/function-not-available-for-call-using-rcpp-package-skeleton-and-compileattrib ; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16581166/rcpp-why-i-can-not-run-the-function-in-my-defined-package ;  any of those useful?

Comment: `devtools::use_rcpp()` 4EVA @DirkEddelbuettel ;-)

Comment: @BenBolker There is no useDynLib in my `NAMESPACE` file. However, even if I added `useDynLib (stormwindmodel)` to that file, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I read the document of `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`. It provides me a detailed of using `Rcpp.package.skeleton()`. However, I was wondering since I already have a R package called `stormwindmodel`, if I run the command `Rcpp.package.skeleton(stormwindmodel)`, it would create a `stormwindmodel` file under my `stormwindmodel` package file, both `stormwindmodel` file have `NAMESPACE`, `man` , `R`, and etc,. How can I deal with this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are likely missing the `useDynLib(<pkg>)` entry in your `NAMESPACE` file. If you're using Roxygen and following the examples in the book, you need to include the following content in an R file (the best guess at this point is you missed this step):

```
#' @useDynLib your-package-name
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL
```

The `@useDynLib <pkg>` Roxygen directive instructs the `roxygen2` package to include a `useDynLib(<pkg>)` in the `NAMESPACE` file whenever you re-document the package.

Did you remember to add the associated lines above to an R file in your package in the R folder (e.g. at `R/package-init.R`), and re-document the package after adding that? If you've done everything correctly, you should see `useDynLib(<pkg>)` added to the `NAMESPACE` file, with `<pkg>` replaced by the actual name of your package.

It should be noted that `devtools::use_rcpp()` does *not* do this automatically for you -- after running the function, it instructs you that you need to do this step manually:

```
> devtools::use_rcpp()
Adding Rcpp to LinkingTo and Imports
* Creating `src/`.
* Ignoring generated binary files.
Next, include the following roxygen tags somewhere in your package:

#' @useDynLib sparklyr
#' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
NULL

Then run document()
```